Influxdb dockerized account can’t be used on an other device?
I pulled influxDb container on docker, created my account by the port connected to the container and worked with it by creating buckets.
I wanted to give access to my collegues by giving my credentials, but when they pull the container, go on localhost:8086 and put my credentials they created a brand new account with the same name but different userID.
So i tried to add to my organization their userID but I get that they don’t exist(i didn’t misscopied the userID).
